# Possible to change message date through MAPI props?

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

Is it possible to change any of the email message dates (sent, received, modified...) through MAPI properties? I'm looking at the IMessage interface and don't see anything related to that. Am I looking in the wrong place?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842097.aspx

```
IMessage : IMAPIProp
  IMessage::CreateAttach
  IMessage::DeleteAttach
  IMessage::GetAttachmentTable
  IMessage::GetRecipientTable
  IMessage::ModifyRecipients
  IMessage::OpenAttach
  IMessage::SetReadFlag
  IMessage::SubmitMessage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all properties except for `PR_CREATION_TIME` and `PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME` can be modified. You need to use `IMessage::SetProps` (that method is inherited from the `IMAPIProp` interface).